# Naming Tags (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, naming

Is it a good idea to name important tags with # prefix eg #reviews, #articles (somewhat like the twitter hashtag) to separate them from thousands of regular tags?

What would be its effect on SEO and will the '#' be stripped when used in a URL?

Comment: Should be moved to superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using '-' has been proven good.. example like review-articles are much better seo wise.

And, if you use # in the title then it would be stripped from permalink structure.